# ThroughPut Unit and Partition Count

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, throughput

I have question regarding Partition Count with relate to TUs. We have a below configuration and 3 Tus for the NameSpace, than will it have an impact based on no of partition for each eventhub, also should we just create partition count as 32 for better performance?. FYI we are using standard plan and kept partition count higher for first one as it receives more messages. We also use batch method to send messages to evenhub.

[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a potential issue if having 3 TUs. if the namespace has 3 TUs, then in a minute, the maximum size of ingress is 1M * 60 * 3 = 180M/minute, but in the table you posted, the total size is larger than 180M(109+58+39).

And for TU and partition count, you should take a look at [How many partitions do I need?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#how-many-partitions-do-i-need), [Partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#partitions). And you can follow the guide below from the above articles:

We recommend that you balance 1:1 throughput units and partitions to achieve optimal scale. A single partition has a guaranteed ingress and egress of up to one throughput unit. While you may be able to achieve higher throughput on a partition, performance is not guaranteed. This is why we strongly recommend that the number of partitions in an event hub be greater than or equal to the number of throughput units.

Answer (score 1):

Plan as max 1 MB/sec per partition. In other words, think each partition as an individual stream which can process 1 MB/sec traffic at most. That said, your current configuration looks alright to me. However, you can still consider increasing partition counts depending on your traffic growth trajectory.